# SQL ORACLE Performance

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column with a count (+1) based on a column in the same table matching that of another, I have successfully tried below:

```
UPDATE table1 p
     SET f_dup_count = (case when exists (SELECT 1
                                          FROM table2 a
                                          WHERE a.f = p.f AND
                                                a.a_id = p.a_id
                                         )
                             then f_dup_count + 1
                             else 0
                         end);
```

However, the processing time is quite High. I there a way to do this as a 'create table as select' in order to improve performance, or any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: Why would you want to create another table?  Please show the table schema, relevant indexes, and run an explain plan.

Answer (score 2):

This query will run faster if you have an index on:

```
table2(f, a_id)
```

You can create the index by doing:

```
create index table2_f_pid on table2(f, a_id);
```

In this case, the order of `f` and `a_id` in the index doesn't make a difference, so an index on `a_id, f` would work just as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this with no noticeable difference.

CREATE INDEX table2_IND ON table2 ("F", "A_ID")

Am I doing something wrong? The update seems to be the bulk of the cost in either case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update just the records that have a duplicate I would write:

```
update table1 p
   set f_dup_count = f_dup_count + 1
 where exists (select 1
          from table2 a
         where a.f = p.f
           and a.a_id = p.a_id)
```